# Enable woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees in the MiniCart? is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a discount added via woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees.
This doesn't work in the minicart unfortunately and the subtotal isn't really correct in the minicart as a result.

Any idea how I could make it work?
Thank you,

Comment: You mean the [woo-minicart](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-minicart/) plugin? At first glance it uses `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal()` so you'll need a hook that counts for that. Do you want to actually show the discount or just the discounted total?

Comment: However internally WooCommerce defines 'subtotal' as 'costs before discounts'. So you probably ought to modify the minicart plugin to show subtotal - discounts rather than subtotal.

Comment: @Rup Hi. I don't mean that plugin. I mean the top right minicart that's in most themes (including storefront) when you hover over the cart. This one: https://prnt.sc/t9vvw8  If I add a discount via woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees the discounts / correct subtotal will not show there. Would only show in the cart page.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, just a small start.
I haven't found any answer to do this via a WooCommerce native function. So looks like we would have to do it ourselves. This will add the discounts in the minicart:

```
add_action('woocommerce_mini_cart_contents', 'addminicart');
            function addminicart(){
                $fees = WC()->cart;
                $fees->calculate_fees();
                $feesresult = $fees->get_fees();
                foreach ($feesresult as $fee){
                    echo $fee->name.': '.$fee->amount.'<br />';
                }
            }
```

2 problems remain:

- modifying the total/subtotal to include these
- dealing with cart fragments / caching. I think this is a bit theme dependant. Anyway, this code will clear it via JS: `$(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');`